# Allow iframes from specific sites?

Tags: iframe, wp-kses

With kses filtering, WordPress only allows a subset of html tags within a post or page, and one of the tags it strips out is the `<iframe>` tag (for many good reasons).

I'd like to allow editors to include iframes where the src is from one of our other subdomains, or from a specified whitelist of domains, but still strip out other unknown src's.  It is straightforward to bypass kses to allow all `<iframe>`'s, but is it possible to only allow certain domains?

Comment: What do you think about making it with shortcodes? Take a look at this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/. Find there shortcode process function and add validation for domain with parse_url  function. If this solution is good for you, I can help to write the function

Comment: Thats a great idea! I got caught up looking up wp-kses options and didn't even consider a shortcode.  Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd [register an embed handler](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler) with `wp_embed_register_handler`. This gives you the added benefit of being able to just copy and paste the url into the editor as well as seeing a preview of the iframe.

```
add_action( 'init', 'se238330_register_embed_handler' );

function se238330_register_embed_handler() {
    wp_embed_register_handler( 
        'joetek',
        '#http://subdomain.yourdomain\.com/(.+)/?#i',
        'wp_embed_handler_joetek'
    );
}

function wp_embed_handler_embed_name( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr ) {
    $embed = sprintf(
        '<iframe class="joetek-website" src="http://subdomain.yourdomain.com/%1$s/" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>',
        esc_attr( $matches[1] )
    );

    return apply_filters( 'embed_joetek', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
}
```

The code above assumes that joetek is the name of your embed :) You'd need to update the regex in the second parameter of `wp_embed_register_handler` as well as in the callback function to match the pages you want to be able to embed on your website.